# Mysql Workbench - Error Code: 5. Out of memory

Tags: runtime-error, out-of-memory, mysql-workbench, load-data-infile, import-from-csv

I am using myworkbench 8.0 to import data to MySql 8.0.32 from a 16G csv file. I get "**Error Code: 5. Out of memory (Needed 784334881 bytes)**". Machine spec: Win 10, 8Gb ram. CSV is | delimited.

Import statement used:

LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/IT14_Prov20230412P.csv"
INTO TABLE _original
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

My.ini was set as follows:

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

I tried changing to innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G. The problem still persist.

To test the file content, I tried looping through the file using Python. The content looks fine but the loop always stops at line 411452 and all of a sudden, the machine freezes with no error. I don't know if stopping of the loop, machine freezing and the error above are related.

Here is my Python test code:

with open(file_name, "r", encoding='latin-1') as file:
csv_dict_reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter='|')
for row in csv_dict_reader:
print(csv_dict_reader.line_num - 1, row)

Comment: Sounds like you should run the import from a shell instead - but neither your approach nor mine is related to programming, which makes your question off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks for the response Nico, much appreciated. I tried the shell route but the import still stops with message "Error 5 (HY000): Out of memory (Needed 784334881). The machine does not freeze when using the shell however.

Comment: Can you load the 'back half' of the csv with IGNORE 411452 ROWS; ?  If so Get the back half, then limit the front half and put them together.   Sounds like there may be BLOB at row 411452.

Comment: Wilson, your suspicion looks correct, thanks a million. I used IGNORE 411452 and got a similar error, 411453 had the same issue but 411454 processed successfully without an error.